# tiny mce spell checker

Tags: javascript, tinymce

does any know if tiny MCE support spell checking?

Comment: Yes, mice need a tiny spell checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is at least one plugin to add a spellchecking feature : [TinyMCE:Plugins/spellchecker](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/spellchecker) *(quoting)* :

> This plugin adds spellchecker
>   functionality to TinyMCE by providing
>   a new button that performs a AJAX call
>   to a backend PHP page that uses
>   PSpell/ASpell or Google spellchecker.

So, I'd say TinyMCE doesn't natively *support* spellchecking... But, as long as you can install that plugin *(Which has some requirements, especially in terms of server software)*, things should be OK ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search for "tinymce spell" revealed: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/spellchecker

So it appears that spell checking is not built in, but requires an additional plugin.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE ships with an internal plugin for spell checking, however, this plugin only makes use of pre-installed browser extensions/add-ons/dictionaries. In the case of IE, it asks the user for installation of IESpell - if not available already.

To enable this feature, place the following settings in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
plugins: "iespell,spellchecker",
theme_advanced_buttons1: "spellchecker,iespell,|,...
```

Only *one* button will appear in the toolbar: IE will only show a button for IESpell. Firefox, chrome, etc., will only show the default spellchecker button. If no dictionary is installed in Firefox, this spell checker plugin will not have any effect. If available, you can activate/deactivate spell checking in the tiny textarea.

If you wan't to consistently provide spell checking, use the [PHP plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) - as mentioned above. This plugin also works with Python/Django in combination with [PyEnchant](http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/).